# How can I access imageData from a renderTarget?

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

I'm a university masters degree student in Computer Graphics, I'm having difficulty using three.js to access the image data(pixels) of a texture created with a EffectComposer.

The first composer (**composer**) is using a line detection shader to find road lines in a lane, and put the result in a renderTarget (**rt_Binary**). My second composer (**fcomposer2**) uses a shader that paints an area green if is within a certain space.

The plan was to render the **composer** first and after analysing the **rt_Binary** image i could determine the limits.

I found some functions that allow me to get the imagedata (**getImageData(image)** and **getPixel(imagedata, x, y)**) but they only work on these occasions:

```
                // before image 
                var imagedata = getImageData(videoTexture.image);
                // processed image
                var imagedata2 = getImageData(renderer.domElement);
```

If a put the first composer to render to screen, i get the correct values for the limits, but when i put the second composer, i get the wrong values for the limits.
Is there any way to get the imageData from a **renderTarget**? is so, how?

Edit1:

Here's the code for script that i use for the html:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head>
    <title>Tests WebGL</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="three.js/build/three.js"></script>
        <script src="js/CopyShader.js"></script>
        <script src="js/EffectComposer.js"></script>
        <script src="js/MaskPass.js" ></script> 
        <script src="js/RenderPass.js" ></script>
        <script src="js/ShaderPass.js"></script>
        <script src="js/stats.min.js" ></script>
        <!-- Shaders -->
        <script src="js/shaders/KernelShader.js" ></script>
        <script src="js/shaders/SimpleShader.js"></script>
        <script src="js/shaders/MyShader.js"></script>
        <script src="js/shaders/BinaryShader.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            var scene, fscene, sceneF;
            var camera;
            var renderer, rt_Binary;
            var composer;
            var stats;
            var fmaterial;

            var videoTexture;
            var videoWidth = 480;
            var videoHeight = 270;

            var rendererWidth = videoWidth;
            var rendererHeight = videoHeight;

            var x_max = 345;//videoWidth*0.72; //
            var x_min = 120;//videoWidth*0.25; //
            var y_max = 189;//videoHeight*0.7 ;
            var y_min = 148;//videoHeight*0.55;

      //      var ml=0.0, mr=0.0, mm=0.0;
      //      var bl=0.0, br=0.0, bm=0.0;

            var yMaxL = 0, yMinL = 0, yMaxR = 0, yMinR = 0;
            var xMaxL = 0, xMinL = 0, xMaxR = 0, xMinR = 0;

            var frame = 0;
            // init the scene
            window.onload = function() {
                renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer(
                        {
                            antialias: true, // to get smoother output
                            preserveDrawingBuffer: true // to allow screenshot
                        });
                renderer.setClearColor(0xffffff, 1);
                renderer.autoClear = false;
                renderer.setSize(rendererWidth, rendererHeight);
                document.getElementById('container').appendChild(renderer.domElement);

                //add stats
                stats = new Stats();
                stats.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
                stats.domElement.style.top = '0px';
                document.getElementById('container').appendChild(stats.domElement);

                // create Main scene
                scene = new THREE.Scene();
                camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(35, rendererWidth / rendererHeight, 1, 10000);
                camera.position.set(0, 1, 6);
                scene.add(camera);

                // define video element
                video = document.createElement('video');
                // video.src = 'GOPR0007.webm';
                video.src = 'output.webm';
                video.width = videoWidth;
                video.height = videoHeight;
                video.autoplay = true;
                video.loop = true;

                //create 3d object and apply video texture to it
                var videoMesh = new THREE.Object3D();
                scene.add(videoMesh);

                videoTexture = new THREE.Texture(video);

                var geom = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(1, 1);
                material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: videoTexture});

                var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geom, material);
                videoMesh.add(mesh);

                var renderTargetParameters = { minFilter: THREE.LinearFilter, magFilter: THREE.LinearFilter, format: THREE.RGBFormat, stencilBufer: false };
                rt_Binary =  new THREE.WebGLRenderTarget( videoWidth, videoHeight, renderTargetParameters );

                // Composers

               // composer = new THREE.EffectComposer(renderer, renderTarget2); 
                composer = new THREE.EffectComposer(renderer, rt_Binary );
                composer.addPass(new THREE.RenderPass(scene, camera));


                var simple = new SimpleShader.Class(videoWidth, videoHeight);
                var simEffect = new THREE.ShaderPass(simple.shader);
                composer.addPass(simEffect);

                var ef = new BinaryShader.Class(videoWidth, videoHeight, 1.1, [-2,-2,-2,0,0,0,2,2,2]);
                var effect = new THREE.ShaderPass(ef.shader);
                composer.addPass(effect);

                var copyPass = new THREE.ShaderPass(THREE.CopyShader);
          //      copyPass.renderToScreen = true;
                composer.addPass(copyPass);


                //New scene                 
                sceneF = new THREE.Scene();
                sceneF.add(camera);

                var videoMesh2 = new THREE.Object3D();
                sceneF.add(videoMesh2);

                var geomF = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(1, 1);
                var materialF = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: videoTexture});

                var meshF = new THREE.Mesh(geomF, materialF);
                sceneF.add(meshF);

                fcomposer2 = new THREE.EffectComposer(renderer );
                fcomposer2.addPass(new THREE.RenderPass(sceneF, camera));

                fcomposer2.addPass(simEffect);

                var ef1 = new MyShader.Class(videoWidth, videoHeight, [yMaxL,yMinL,xMaxL,xMinL,yMaxR,yMinR,xMaxR,xMinR], videoTexture);
                var effect1 = new THREE.ShaderPass(ef1.shader);
                fcomposer2.addPass(effect1);

                var copyPass2 = new THREE.ShaderPass(THREE.CopyShader);
                copyPass2.renderToScreen = true;
                fcomposer2.addPass(copyPass2);

                animate();
            }

            // animation loop
            function animate() {
                // loop on request animation loop
                // - it has to be at the begining of the function
                requestAnimationFrame(animate);

                // do the render
                render();
                stats.update();
                if ((frame % 50) == 0) {
                    console.log("frame ", frame, " ");

                    console.log("yMaxL: ", yMaxL, " ");
                    console.log("yMinL: ", yMinL, " ");
                    console.log("xMaxL: ", xMaxL, " ");
                    console.log("xMinL: ", xMinL, " ");

                    console.log("yMaxR: ", yMaxR, " ");
                    console.log("yMinR: ", yMinR, " ");
                    console.log("xMaxR: ", xMaxR, " ");
                    console.log("xMinR: ", xMinR, " ");

                    manipulatePixels();
                }
                frame = frame + 1;
                yMaxL = 0, yMinL = 0, yMaxR = 0, yMinR = 0;
                xMaxL = 0, xMinL = 0, xMaxR = 0, xMinR = 0;

            }

            // render the scene
            function render() {
                if (video.readyState === video.HAVE_ENOUGH_DATA) {
                    videoTexture.needsUpdate = true;
                }

                // actually render the scene
                renderer.clear();
                composer.render();                    

                var left_x = new Array();
                var left_y = new Array();
                var l = 0;

                var right_x = new Array();
                var right_y = new Array();
                var r = 0;

              if (frame == 200) {    
                    var imagedata2 = getImageData(renderer.domElement); 

                    var middle = imagedata2.width / 2;

                    for (var x=x_min; x < x_max; x=x+1) {
                        for (var y=y_min; y < y_max; y=y+1) {
                            var pixel = getPixel(imagedata2, x, y);
                            if (pixel.g > 0)
                                {
                                    //console.log(pixel);
                                    if (x < middle) {
                                        left_x[l] = x;
                                        left_y[l] = y;                                    
                                        l++;
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        right_x[r] = x;
                                        right_y[r] = y;
                                        r++;
                                    }
                                }
                        }
                    }

                  lineEquation(left_x, left_y, right_x, right_y);


               }

               fcomposer2.render();
            }

            function lineEquation(left_x,left_y,right_x,right_y) {
                var newYMAX = left_y[0];
                var newYMIN = left_y[0];

                var maximosL = new Array();
                var minimosL = new Array();

      //left
                for (var i=1; i < left_y.length; i++) {
                    if (left_y[i]>newYMAX) newYMAX = left_y[i];
                    else {
                        if (left_y[i]<newYMIN) newYMIN = left_y[i];
                    }
                }

                yMaxL = newYMAX;
                yMinL = newYMIN;    
          //      yMaxL = ymaxL/videoHeight;
          //      yMinL = yminL/videoHeight;    


                var pmin=0, pmax=0;
                for (var i=0; i < left_y.length; i++) {
                    if (left_y[i] === newYMAX) { 
               //         console.log(left_y[i]);
               //         console.log(left_x[i]);
                        maximosL[pmax] = left_x[i]; 
                        pmax++;
                    }

                }
                for (var j=0; j < left_y.length; j++) {
                    if (left_y[j] === newYMIN) {
                 //      console.log(left_y[j]);
                 //      console.log(left_x[j]);
                       minimosL[pmin] = left_x[j];
                       pmin++;
                    }
                }

             //   console.log(maximosL);
             //   console.log(minimosL);

                var sumMAX = 0, sumMIN = 0;
                for (var i=0; i< maximosL.length; i++) {
                    sumMAX = sumMAX + maximosL[i];
                }

                for (var j=0; j< minimosL.length; j++) {
                     sumMIN = sumMIN + minimosL[j];
                }

                xMaxL = sumMAX/maximosL.length;
                xMinL = sumMIN/minimosL.length;

         //       xMaxL /= videoWidth;
         //       xMinL /= videoWidth;

     //right      
                var maximosR = new Array();
                var minimosR = new Array();

                newYMAX = right_y[0];
                newYMIN = right_y[0];

                pmin=0; pmax=0;
                for (var i=0; i < right_y.length; i++) {
                    if (right_y[i]> newYMAX) newYMAX = right_y[i];
                    else {
                        if (right_y[i]< newYMIN) newYMIN = right_y[i];
                    }
                }

                 yMaxR = newYMAX;
                 yMinR = newYMIN;
          //      yMaxR = ymaxR/videoHeight;
          //      yMinR = yminR/videoHeight;


                for (var i=0; i < right_y.length; i++) {
                    if (right_y[i] === newYMAX) 
                        {maximosR[pmax] = right_x[i]; pmax++;}
                    if (right_y[i] === newYMIN)
                        {minimosR[pmin] = right_x[i]; pmin++;}
                }

    //            console.log(maximosR);
    //            console.log(minimosR);

                xMaxR=0;
                for (var i=0; i< maximosR.length; i++) {
                    xMaxR += maximosR[i];
                }
                xMinR=0;
                for (var i=0; i< minimosR.length; i++) {
                    xMinR += minimosR[i];
                }

      //         console.log(xMaxR);
      //         console.log(xMinR);

                xMaxR /= maximosR.length;
                xMinR /= minimosR.length;

       //        console.log(xMaxR);
       //        console.log(xMinR);

       //         xMinR /= videoWidth;
       //         xMaxR /= videoWidth;



            }

            function manipulatePixels() {
                // imagem antes
                var imagedata = getImageData(videoTexture.image);
                // imagem processada
                var imagedata2 = getImageData(renderer.domElement);

  //              console.log(getPixel(imagedata, 480 - 1, 270 - 1));
  //              console.log(getPixel(imagedata2, 480 - 1, 270 - 1));

            }

            function getImageData(image) {
                var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
                canvas.width = image.width;
                canvas.height = image.height;

                var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
                context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);

                return context.getImageData(0, 0, image.width, image.height);
            }

            function getPixel(imagedata, x, y) {
                var position = (x + imagedata.width * y) * 4, data = imagedata.data;
                return {r: data[ position ], g: data[ position + 1 ], b: data[ position + 2 ], a: data[ position + 3 ]};
            }

            function findLineByLeastSquares(values_x, values_y) {
                var sum_x = 0;
                var sum_y = 0;
                var sum_xy = 0;
                var sum_xx = 0;

                /*
                * We'll use those variables for faster read/write access.
                */
                var x = 0;
                var y = 0;
                var values_length = values_x.length;

                if (values_length != values_y.length) {
                    throw new Error('The parameters values_x and values_y need to have same size!');
                }

                /*
                * Nothing to do.
                */
                if (values_length === 0) {
                    return [ [], [] ];
                }

                /*
                * Calculate the sum for each of the parts necessary.
                */
                for (var v = 0; v < values_length; v++) {
                    x = values_x[v];
                    y = values_y[v];
                    sum_x += x;
                    sum_y += y;
                    sum_xx += (x*x);
                    sum_xy += (x*y);
                }

                  console.log (sum_x);
                  console.log(sum_y);
                  console.log(sum_xx);
                  console.log(sum_xy);
                  console.log(values_length);
                /*
                * Calculate m and b for the formular:
                * y = x * m + b
                */
               var m = (sum_x*sum_y - values_length*sum_xy) / (sum_x*sum_x - values_length*sum_xx);
               var b = (sum_y - (m*sum_x))/values_length;

               //console.log([m,b]);

                return [m, b];
            }

            //resize method
            /**window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);
             function onWindowResize() {
             camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
             camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

             renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
             } */
        </script>
```

Edit2 : Some images of what i'm trying to do: Image 1 shows the results from **composer** on the console, the limits i get from the **lineEquation** function are the correct ones for what i intend to do, but in Image 2 shows the results from **fcomposer2** (fixed area) and on the console, the limits are the wrong ones.

![Image1]: http://prntscr.com/1ays73
![Image2]: http://prntscr.com/1ays0j

Edit3 : 
By "access" i mean to be able to read the values of the pixels from the texture created by the **binaryShader**. 
For example, in image1 the lines are painted in blue/green tone, I wanted to search the position of the pixels (x,y) in the image that the renderTarget would save. If i could find those pixels, i could adapt the green area in image2 to fit between the road lines.

This processing is need to make the green area overlap the current driving lane the user is currently on, if i can't get those points, i can't identify a lane.

Comment: I don't think many people are going to download a zip file from someone they don't know. Moreover it makes the question hard to understand without it. Try posting the code in the question please.

Comment: Sorry, i have never asked a question online before. Hope it's clearer now what I'm trying to do.

Comment: You have to make it easy for people to help you. What do you mean "access" image data from a render target? Is all the processing relevant to the question? Can you make a simple example and ask a specific question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work. Apparently i forgot to declare the **fcomposer2** in the beginning of the script. 
Thanks for the responses/comments, and sorry for the inconvenience.